# How can we recreate binary file at receiver side using bytearray in Python and XBee

Tags: python, xbee

i am learning the Python and XBee . I have a query regarding data transmission . Can we transfer any binary file using xbee ? i tried it using below code . But i think something is wrong in the code . I am not able to recreate the binary file at another end. I used byte array . Instead of exe , there may be zip file or image file .
     Can any one  point out what exactly i am doing wrong ?
     thanks in advance

My Code

### Sender Side

```
 PORT ='COM4' # or '/dev/ttyUSB0'

 BAUD_RATE = 115200

 ser1 = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

 xbee1 = ZigBee(ser1,escaped=True)

 with open("any.exe",'rb+') as infile:

 # Byte by byte transmission

 for i in range(1, os.path.getsize("any.exe") ):

                data_to_send = infile.read(1024) 

                ser1.write(data_to_send)
                ## or
                xbee1.tx(frame='0x01',
                         dest_addr=self.DEST_ADDR ,
                         dest_addr_long= self.DEST_ADDR_LONG ,
                         data= data_to_send
                         )


 time.sleep(0.50)
 ser1.write('\~')
 ser1.write('<')
```

=================================================================

### Receiver Side

```
    bytearr = bytearray()
    starttime =datetime.datetime.now()
    prevline=''
    while (True):

            line = ser1.read()         
            #  line = xbee1.wait_read_frame()

            if(line == '~') and (prevline == '<'):
                break

            bytearr.extend(line)

            prevline=line

print '-------------------------'

f=open("any.exe","wb+")

f.write(bytearr)

f.close()
```

======================================================================
 **Below code is equivalent code and it works fine .**

```
import os

def clonningFile() :

    bytearr = bytearray()
    with open("Untitled.wma",'rb+') as infile:
        for i in range(1, os.path.getsize("Untitled.wma") ):
                    data_to_send = infile.read(1024)
                    bytearr.extend(data_to_send)

    f=open("Untitled2.wma","wb+")
    f.write(bytearr)
    f.close()


clonningFile()
```

Comment: You've said that your code doesn't work to recreate the file on the receiver side. But what does happen? Are you getting errors, or is the file corrupted? Or does the `while` loop on the receiver side never end? I don't know much about serial communication, but my guess would be that the `~` and `<` characters you're sending at the end are getting mixed in with the last chunk of the file data and not getting recognized, but who knows. You might want to make your receiver print out relevant info like `len(line)` as it runs, for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: Like @Blckknght said.  What happens?  How big is the resulting file?  If you do a binary compare, are they even close to matching?  What if you start simple with a one-line text file.  Does that work?  If you replace the XBee radios with a wired serial connection, does that work? Have you confirmed the XBee modules are joined together and pass data transparently?

Comment: Please have a look at the output

Comment: ('Receiving  Bytes stream.....', 1)
Received Bytes Size =  1  at  00:42:37.408000
Received Bytes Size =  368  at  00:42:38.673000
Received Bytes Size =  643  at  00:43:01.317000
Received Bytes Size =  899  at  00:43:02.248000
Received Bytes Size =  1174  at  00:43:17.527000
Received Bytes Size =  1541  at  00:43:18.909000
Received Bytes Size =  1799  at  00:43:31.355000
Received Bytes Size =  2166  at  00:43:46.579000
Received Bytes Size =  2533  at  00:43:47.959000
Received Bytes Size =  2699  at  00:43:59.338000
Received Bytes Size =  3066  at  00:44:04.316000

Comment: Now I found that i misplaced some bits . Also, the special characters  ~ were mixed in the actual stream. Now i am able to recreate the binary file. But the second issue came up. To transfer 3066 bytes or 3 kilobytes , it took 2 min  . Can't we speed up the bytes transmission . i am using  serial mode XBee s2 and 115200 baud rate.